# Spring MVC question marks instead polish letters.with Charset or java encoding (polish letters)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, character-encoding

In my Spring MVC project i've got couple of .jsp views with defined charset like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1250"
pageEncoding="windows-1250" session="true" %>
```

In  element there is also a meta:

```
<meta charset="windows-1250">
```

I'm using eclipse with tomcat 8 for realising and debugging. In web.xml i've got defined encoding filter like this:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>WINDOWS-1250</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

In my Controller class (in appropriate RequestMapper) i am printing some charsets:

```
System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println("file.encoding=" + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println("Default Charset in Use=" + getDefaultCharSet());
```

When i pass some polish letters in .jsp view (passedby ModelAtribute), for example: abcdeęść in Controller (and in database as result) printed value is : **abcde???** . The output for above System.out.printlns... is:

```
Default Charset=windows-1250
file.encoding=windows-1250
Default Charset=windows-1250
Default Charset in Use=Cp1250
```

Any ideas where is problem with those polish letters ?

**edit**
The same outputs with UTF-8 defined

```
Default Charset=UTF-8
file.encoding=UTF-8
Default Charset=UTF-8
Default Charset in Use=UTF8
```

String abcdeąść is printed as: **abcdeÄÅÄ**

**EDIT :**

When i change all encoding to UTF-8 problem is the same. But, what i notice:
When i firstly decode text from ISO-8859-1 and then encode it to UTF-8 printed and saved values are **OK**:

```
byte ptext[] = email.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); 
String value = new String(ptext, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); 
System.out.println("Value email: " + value);
```

In every .jsp file i have those lines with UTF-8 charsets, files are encoded in UTF-8 , java classes either and in some way values from .jsp form are in ISO-8859-1. How is that possible ?

Comment: Did you try 'iso-8859-1' or 'UTF8'?

Comment: For UTF-8 problem is almost the same. I've add some details in question above.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and i saw that the polish string shows correctly with the following configuration..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

also inside head tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and my encoding filter configuration

```
CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
filter.setForceEncoding(true);
http.addFilterBefore(filter, CsrfFilter.class);
http.csrf().disable();
```

So i think if you change all that you will be fine. Also my configuration is not in xml but is the same as you can see except the encoding string part.

My Java filles encoding inside eclipse is UTF-8.

Comment: I did what you describe above but it doesn't work. But i made some progress.

When i firstly decode text from ISO-8859-1 and then encode it to UTF-8 printed and saved values are OK :

byte ptext[] = email.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
String value = new String(ptext, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("Value email: " + value);

Comment: In every .jsp file i have those lines with UTF-8 charsets, files are encoded in UTF-8 , java classes either and in some way values from .jsp form are in ISO-8859-1. How is that possible ?